# Firefox loses focus when switching keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard-layout, firefox, cinnamon

I use many different keyboard layouts and I do change them often. That is why I defined keyboard shortcuts in Cinnamon (alt+F1, alt+F2 and so on). Now, this works ok in the applications I use, except for Firefox, where after switching to another layout, I have to click to the place where I stopped writing, before I can continue further.

Is there any way to go around this behavior?

Comment: Did you find any solution? Firefox on elementaryos has exactly same issue even if I use Alt+Shift shortcut to switch layout, the issue appears on some sites, not everywere, at duckduckgo for example it is, but not at google.

Comment: Still relevant, unfortunately. Seems to only affect duckduckgo, and no other website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alt+F1,F2 are defined to open the application menu and application finder (I don't know how they are called in Cinnamon), so, changing the keyboard combination, to another should solve your issue.